# Compare content of two pandas dataframes even if the rows are differently ordered

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes, which rows are in different orders but contain the same columns. 
My goal is to easily compare the two dataframes and confirm that they both contain the same rows.

I have tried the "equals" function, but there seems to be something I am missing, because the results are not as expected:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({1: [10,15,30], 2: [20,25,40]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [30,10,15], 2: [40,20,25]})
df_1.equals(df_2)
```

I would expect that the outcome returns True, because both dataframes contain the same rows, just in a different order, but it returns False.

Comment: Cant you sort first?

Comment: I think it is not so easy in the real example, because I would have to sort by several columns. Would this simultaneous sorting work?

Comment: I believe so... gave it a try, check it out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify columns for sorting in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) - in my solution sorting by all columns and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for default indices in both `DataFrames`:

```
df11 = df_1.sort_values(by=df_1.columns.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)
df21 = df_2.sort_values(by=df_2.columns.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df11.equals(df21))
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try sorting and reseting index

```
df_1.sort_values(by=[1,2]).equals(df_2.sort_values(by=[1,2]).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the situation if both columns and rows of two similar dataframes are differently ordered:

**Order the columns**

```
df_1 = df_1[df_2.columns]
```

**Choose the column to sort the rows w.r.t.**

```
ref_len = 0
for col in df_1.columns:
    if(len(set(df_1[col])) > ref_len):
        final_col = col
        ref_len = len(set(df_1[col]))
```

**Order the rows**

```
df11 = df_1.sort_values(by=[final_col]).reset_index(drop=True)
df21 = df_2.sort_values(by=[final_col]).reset_index(drop=True)

df11.equals(df21)
```